# Integrating google docs into website

Tags: iframe, content-management-system, google-docs

The "publish" feature of google docs looks like a perfect way to put all contents of a site away, without need to manage pictures and other content in CMS and move it all to google docs by embedding the published documents on a website.

However google allows iframe embedding and this has some obvious disadvantages (like all links will open inside iframe) - this is one probelm.

Another thing is that i can't manage to set the height of the iframe so that it fits the inner document - that's another thing.

Do you have any suggestions on how to overcome this problems? maybe there are other ways to embed a document into a website? maybe there are other docs-services that will not have such disadvantages?

In the end i want to make it transparent to viewer of the page and easy for the maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider using http://www.scribd.com/  it might be a bit easier to implement than Google docs.